# How to update a class inside modal body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a class `<div id="modal-data"></div>` which is inside a modal

This is the code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymdl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="color-line"></div>
                            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">Select Theme</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="js-source-states" style="width: 100%" id="timezone">
                            <div id="modal-data"></div>
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

With this piece of code:

```
$("#mymdl").modal({
    fadeDuration: 1000,
    fadeDelay: 1,
    closeClass: 'icon-remove',
    closeText: 'X'
});

var mymodal1 = $('#mymdl');
mymodal1.find('#modal-data').html("<option value='x'>Create</option>");
```

But its not working... Can any one help?

Comment: i see `$("#mymdl").modal({` but i'm cant find any html element with `id="mymdl"`

Comment: By the way you'll need bootstrap to use .modal, if you don't jQuery will say that ".modal is not a function"

Comment: `<div class="modal fade" id="mymdl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
......
.....
</div>`

Comment: please provide full modal snippet. She only wants her modal to be working. But, according to actual snippet, she's using bootstrap like modal without linking bootstrap so it will never work...

Comment: Why u need to populate `div` inside a `select' tag

Comment: please check , i have edited

Comment: @AnaGabriel pls edit code rather than posting a screenshot of code

Comment: Which type modal you using, Bootstrap or else plugin?

Comment: bootstrap modal

Comment: Please help, I have updated post

Comment: @AnaGabriel You cant append div inside `select` . You really need that?

Comment: You can have `option` tag

Comment: Yes I really need to do that badly

Comment: Why u need a `h1` inside select

Comment: I just post it as example. I need to add `<option value=""></option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

$("#mymdl").modal({
    fadeDuration: 1000,
    fadeDelay: 1,
    closeClass: 'icon-remove',
    closeText: 'X'
});

var mymodal1 = $('#mymdl');
mymodal1.find('#timezone').html("<option>Hi there</option>");

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="mymdl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="color-line"></div>
            <div class="modal-header text-center">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select Theme</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="js-source-states" style="width: 100%" id="timezone">
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DOM structure is wrong you wrote block element `div` inside `select` element which is invalid. It should be like following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mymdl" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="color-line"></div>
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Select Theme</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-sm-10"><select class="js-source-states" style="width: 100%" id="timezone">

        </select>
        <div id="modal-data"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you should write your code under a specific callback, in this case you should in `show.bs.modal` callback:

```
$('#mymdl').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var mymodal1 = $('#mymdl');
    mymodal1.find('#modal-data').html("<h1>HI</h1>");
})
```

Comment: but I need to add something Inside select

Comment: Then you should choose option not div.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.modal-content').find('.modal-body').append('<p>append some html here</p>');
$('.modal-content').find('.modal-body').append('<h1>Hi</h1>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="mdlbtn">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you want. if it is i can explain you

Comment: No sorry, I have a class inside `modal-body` which is `modal-data` I want to change modal-data

Comment: ... It's the logyc that you have to addapt to your project, if you ask for exact working code to your project it seems that you're asking to us for making your homework and you'll be highly downvoted and ignored.
This is a bootstrap modal with a jQuery code that sets html code inside. Simply read the jquery code and change some selectors to see it working on your project.

Comment: post data: Stack Overflow snippets have a `$(document).ready(function(){` by default so you'll need to add the desired event listener to trigger the jQuery i added.